# class registration schema recommendation

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

I am trying to design a database of a class registration relationship. Is this the best way for this situation?

Registration schema

```
 const mongoose = require("mongoose");
//Course Schema
//Faculty can add courses to the DB
const registrationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  courseID: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Course" },
  studentID:{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }

});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Registration", registrationSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a seperate registration collection, why not try modelling using 'Two-way embedding' approach? [refer](http://learnmongodbthehardway.com/schema/schemabasics/#two-way-embedding)

So your **Course** collection will have array of students reference and **Student** collection will have an array of courses reference, for easy retrieval.